# Как сделать чтобы в FragmentPagerAdapter отображалось несколько фрагментов сразу?

Tags: android

Как в FragmentPagerAdapter показать крайние элементы?

Comment: Попробуйте отрицательный внешний отступ поставить: `viewPager.setPageMargin(-100);` Или переопределите в адаптере метод вычисления ширины страницы [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25831393/3212712). Вроде, первый вариант должен лучше работать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не понял. Имеете ввиду сделать чтобы у соседних мест устанавливать setPage?

Comment: Я имею в виду сделать ширину страницы viewPager меньше ширины экрана чтобы были видны соседние страницы. Если вам нужно не это - переформулируйте вопрос. А то он не очень понятен - нет уверенности что я правильно понял вашу проблему.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, уже нашел что надо. Спасибо. Может кому пригодится https://gist.github.com/devunwired/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1